# Angular UI bootstrap typeahead select when there is only one match

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

Is it possible to configure (built in or via a custom directive) the Angular UI bootstrap typeahead so it selects the value if there is only one match? There's the *typeahead-select-on-exact* option, but for this to work, the entered value must match the complete option of the typeahead

See plunker below. I've added the *typeahead-select-on-exact*, so when you type "Portugal" it selects the value. 
The behaviour I would like to achieve is when you type "Portu", the typeahead selects Portugal as well (since this is the only possible match).

```
 <input type="text" typeahead-select-on-exact="true">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ddAsXQuXjOf7rKkKmYuz?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my use case I ended up adding the following to the *getLocation()* method (see the plunker sample in the question)

```
if(response.data.length === 1) {
   $scope.asyncSelected = response.data[0].name
}
```